# GetModuleFileName from MSI

Tags: c++, windows-installer, installation

I try use the "GetModuleFileName" to get current "setup.msi" location use mydll.dll in setup.msi installer.

But always give me "c:\windows\system\setup.msi".
Any body know why ? Plx help .

Comment: `GetModuleFileName` just returns you the name of a module (i.e. executable file or DLL) loaded in the current process. Can you explain what exactly do you need?

Comment: Thanks.
My real problem is How To Extract or Open a Single File From a MSI use custom action DLL.

Comment: MSI file is basicly the same as .CAB archive.

Comment: Thanks lot. I use the other way to solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mention C++ so I'm assuming that you are creating a Type 1 custom action as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368338%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  If this is so, I'm guessing that you are trying to figure out where the install is occurring from so you can reference a file or something.  If so,  check out the [MsiGetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370134%28VS.85%29.aspx) function and the [OriginalDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370562%28VS.85%29.aspx) property.  If that doesn't meet your needs checkout the the MsiSourceList* functions starting with [MsiSourceListGetInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370406%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).